# Вызвать Console.Write

Tags: c#

Console.Write указан в новом потоке,но вызвать нужно его в основном - как мне основной поток получить?

Comment: Консольное приложение? Тогда никак. А почему вы не можете вызвать его в другом потоке?

Comment: @VladD вы знаете что я работаю с unity в у меня консоль работает через -batchmode.Сервер я сделал через TCP - ответ то он возращает,но сообщение не выводит консоль.Видать можно только из основного потока

Comment: Стоит переформулировать вопрос. Например "как в unity записать TCP ответ в консоль". В общем перенести из комментария все подробности в вопрос. Иначе ваш вопрос читают совсем не те люди. Вот я, например, открыл потому что я кое-что знаю о консоли в обычных приложения. Но я не знаю unity. А те кто знают, возможно не откроют, так как вопросы про консоль им не интересны. Это не общий вопрос, потому что в обычном консольном приложении можно выводить в консоль из другого потока.

Comment: @Uranus это та же консоль - просто писать можно с главного потока походу

Comment: А если `delegate`?

Comment: Возможно, тут играет роль то, что ваша строка не оканчивается `\n`. Попробуйте сделать `Console.Out.Flush`.